# Cancellation in this exponential sum?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, exponential-sums, prime-number-theorem

I would like to know whether it is possible to obtain cancellation in the sum

$$\sum_{p \leq X} e^{{2\pi iX}/{p}}$$

where $X$ is a real number that goes to $\infty$, and $p$ denotes a prime number.

Comment: what do you mean by "cancellation" ? you want the sum to equal zero?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I just want the absolute value of the sum, divided by the number of summands, to tend to zero as $X$ grows.

Comment: This seems related to the sum $\sum_{p\le x} \{ x/p \}$, where $\{t\}$ denotes the fractional part of $t$; an asymptotic was found by de la Vallée–Poussin, and [this paper of Eric Naslund](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3195391) gives a nice method for sharpening that asymptotic.